# How can I keep a car window up?

Tags: ford

My car window just fell down while I was driving. I drive a 2002 Ford Explorer. I dont care if I can ever get it to automatically roll up and down again, but how can I get it to stay up?

Answer (score 2):

The only real way to secure it is to open the door panel, look at the rails that allow it to move up and down, and secured it at the point where it is properly stored in the up position.

Comment: The less classy way is duck tape on the top and bottom, but you must maintain the tape to ensure the window stays up. The answer is the only "safe" way, other options might work out, but I recommend just fixing it or having it secured in place.

Comment: Another roadfix is pulling the window up and blocking it with a screwdriver or something slid between window and the bottom frame.